# The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mdeguzis/libregeek/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

I can't update for some reason. I keep getting an error each time `sudo apt-get update`.

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [265 kB]
Get:2 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3,959 B]                                                                                  
Get:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal InRelease [10.5 kB]                                                                             
Get:4 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease [6,257 B]                                                                                     
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]                      
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]    
Get:7 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [199 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]                      
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease [18.0 kB]                              
Get:10 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary focal InRelease [8,435 B]                       
Get:11 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main amd64 Packages [28.2 kB]             
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted Sources [6,472 B]                
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main Sources [847 kB]               
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Sources [9,707 kB]
Get:15 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [92.5 kB]                   
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mdeguzis/libregeek/ubuntu focal InRelease                                       
Get:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal InRelease [17.5 kB]                                                          
Get:18 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [94.2 kB]            
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse Sources [174 kB]                                  
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [970 kB]                        
Get:21 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary focal/main amd64 Packages [6,472 B]                         
Get:22 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [718 kB]                                      
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [506 kB]                        
Get:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu focal InRelease [18.0 kB]                              
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [494 kB]                                    
Get:26 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [98.4 kB]                                        
Get:27 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [163 kB]                                      
Get:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [15.8 kB]                                  
Get:29 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons [367 kB]                                       
Get:30 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary focal/main all Packages [1,028 B]                                           
Get:31 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [29.5 kB]                                                
Get:32 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages [22.0 kB]                
Get:33 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages [8,112 B]            
Get:34 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted Translation-en [6,212 B]           
Get:35 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [392 B]
Get:36 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages [4,642 kB]
Get:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages [8,628 kB]                           
Get:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tatokis/ckb-next/ubuntu focal InRelease [24.3 kB]
Get:39 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe Translation-en [5,124 kB]             
Get:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [3,603 kB]                        
Err:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mdeguzis/libregeek/ubuntu focal Release                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Get:42 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [3,016 kB]          
Get:43 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,794 kB]                         
Get:44 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [640 B]
Get:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [688 B]                                          
Get:46 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [44.3 kB]                                             
Get:47 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [14.3 MB]                                   
Get:48 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [316 B]                               
Get:49 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [2,924 B]                            
Get:50 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [4,200 B]                     
Get:51 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [265 kB]                             
Get:52 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages [74.7 kB]                                     
Get:53 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages [144 kB]                                
Get:54 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse Translation-en [104 kB]                               
Get:55 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [48.4 kB]                             
Get:56 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [23.1 kB]                                   
Get:57 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [192 kB]                                
Get:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [214 B]                            
Get:59 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse DEP-11 128x128 Icons [326 kB]
Get:60 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9,136 B]                             
Get:61 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse Sources [716 B]                   
Get:62 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Sources [4,192 B]                 
Get:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Sources [54.3 kB]                                   
Get:64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Sources [10.1 kB]                              
Get:65 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages [184 kB]                             
Get:66 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages [72.7 kB]                            
Get:67 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main Translation-en [65.5 kB]                           
Get:68 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [24.3 kB]                           
Get:69 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [11.0 kB]                                 
Get:70 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [16.5 kB]                           
Get:71 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                            
Get:72 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons [40.2 kB]
Get:73 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [4,588 B]                           
Get:74 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted i386 Packages [6,356 B]
Get:75 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages [34.3 kB]
Get:76 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted Translation-en [8,916 B]
Get:77 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [324 B]                                                            
Get:78 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages [29.3 kB]                                                                   
Get:79 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages [58.8 kB]                                                                  
Get:80 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe Translation-en [30.9 kB]                                                                  
Get:81 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [52.4 kB]                                                           
Get:82 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [15.4 kB]                                                              
Get:83 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [22.5 kB]                                                              
Get:84 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                               
Get:85 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [38.9 kB]                                                            
Get:86 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [2,476 B]                                                            
Get:87 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,172 B]                                                                
Get:88 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse Translation-en [540 B]                                                                  
Get:89 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]                                                            
Get:90 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse Sources [4,620 B]                                                                        
Get:91 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Sources [184 kB]                                                                               
Get:92 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Sources [59.6 kB]                                                                          
Get:93 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Sources [4,188 B]                                                                        
Get:94 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [359 kB]                                                                        
Get:95 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [212 kB]                                                                         
Get:96 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [136 kB]                                                                        
Get:97 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [3,180 B]                                                              
Get:98 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [209 kB]                                                                 
Get:99 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [48.9 kB]                                                                   
Get:100 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [79.3 kB]                                                                  
Get:101 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                                   
Get:102 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main DEP-11 128x128 Icons [174 kB]                                                                 
Get:103 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [9,464 B]                                                                
Get:104 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages [6,356 B]                                                                 
Get:105 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [34.5 kB]                                                                
Get:106 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted Translation-en [8,968 B]                                                                
Get:107 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [324 B]                                                            
Get:108 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [91.3 kB]                                                                   
Get:109 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [166 kB]                                                                   
Get:110 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [88.1 kB]                                                                  
Get:111 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [186 kB]                                                            
Get:112 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [93.4 kB]                                                              
Get:113 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [167 kB]                                                               
Get:114 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                               
Get:115 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [404 kB]                                                             
Get:116 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [5,580 B]                                                            
Get:117 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [3,312 B]                                                                 
Get:118 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [11.6 kB]                                                                
Get:119 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse Translation-en [3,892 B]                                                                
Get:120 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,468 B]                                                         
Get:121 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 48x48 Icons [29 B]                                                               
Get:122 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [2,638 B]                                                            
Get:123 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                             
Get:124 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse DEP-11 128x128 Icons [29 B]                                                             
Get:125 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu focal/main Sources [26.1 kB]                                                                            
Get:126 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [480 B]                                                            
Get:127 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe Sources [1,700 B]                                                                       
Get:128 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata [112 B]                                                                
Get:129 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]                                                          
Get:130 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages [2,256 B]                                                                 
Get:131 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages [3,088 B]                                                                
Get:132 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe Translation-en [1,448 B]                                                                
Get:133 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [1,768 B]                                                         
Get:134 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [2,809 B]                                                            
Get:135 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [3,944 B]                                                            
Get:136 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons [29 B]                                                             
Get:137 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [6,807 B]                                                          
Get:138 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata [224 B]                                                            
Get:139 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata [116 B]                                                          
Get:140 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [58.0 kB]                                                                     
Get:141 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages [28.2 kB]                                                                      
Get:142 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [21.2 kB]                                                                     
Get:143 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tatokis/ckb-next/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages [616 B]                                                                   
Get:144 http://ppa.launchpad.net/tatokis/ckb-next/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en [228 B]                                                                   
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                                
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mdeguzis/libregeek/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

p.s. I am new to Linux. Three days new.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file). Best advice I can give to a new user: get used to looking things up! Also, you have a helluva lot of PPAs and added sources for "three days new" to Linux. PPA is really not the best way to install software. Always try official repos thru the package manager first.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for

Comment: If you Google the PPA, you will find that the [PPA's Launchpad page](https://launchpad.net/~mdeguzis/+archive/ubuntu/libregeek) doesn't show focal on the dropdown menu for "**published in:**" underneath where it says "**Overview of published packages**".

Comment: PPAs are 3rd party sources, so all security checks (are they from trustworthy sources?, maintained properly?, appropriate for your release? etc) are on you to perform. Issues like this show you're not performing these required checks so potentially opening yourself to security risks.

Comment: Thx for the help. I was able to fix